# Removing item from Cart in Session | Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, model-view-controller, multidimensional-array

I have items in my cart with session and I want to remove the item, my nested array is as follows,

```
[cart_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 1
                    [item_name] => Neapolitan Pizza
                    [price] => 750.00
                    [toppings] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 3
                                    [name] => Chilli
                                    [price] => 100.00
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 4
                                    [name] => Green chilli 
                                    [price] => 100.00
                                )

                        )

                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price_per_item] => 750
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 16
                    [item_name] => Cheesy Garlic Bread
                    [price] => 420.00
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [price_per_item] => 420
                )

        )
```

**Controller Code:-**

In my controller, I have created the following function to `remove each item`. what am I missing here?

**/Cart/remove**

```
public function remove($id){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $list = $this->session->userdata('cart_items');
        if($list){
            foreach ($list as $item=>$value){
                if($id==$value['item_id']){
                    $this->session->unset_userdata($value);
                }
            }
        }
        redirect('Cart/index');

    }
```

In my view, this is how I pass the item id in the anchor tag.

**View:-**

```
<?php $list = $this->session->userdata('cart_items');
        $grand_total=0;
        if($list==Null) {
            print_r("<div><li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed'>There are no items in the your cart</li></div>");
            $sub_total=0;
        }else{
            $sub_total=0;
            foreach ($list as $item=>$value){
                echo "<li class='list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed'>";
                if($value['item_id']<16) {

                    print_r("<div>" . $value['item_id'] . "</div>");
                    print_r("<div>" . $value['item_name'] . "</div>");
                    print_r("<div>" . $value['price'] . "</div>");

                    // toppings array is empty 
                    $toppings_price = 0;
                    if ($value['toppings'] == null) {
                        print_r("<div>No toppings selected</div>");
                    } else {
                        foreach ($value['toppings'] as $val) {
                            // printing topping names
                            print_r("");
                            print_r($val['name']);
                            print_r(",");
                            $toppings_price = $toppings_price + $val['price'];
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    print_r("<div>" . $value['item_id'] . "</div>");
                    print_r("<div>" . $value['item_name'] . "</div>");
                    print_r("<div>" . $value['price'] . "</div>");
                }

                print_r("<div>".$value['quantity']."</div>");
                print_r("<div><a href='".base_url()."index.php/Cart/remove/".$value['item_id']."' class='btn btn-danger'>Remove</a></div>");
                echo "</li>";

                //sub total
                if($value['item_id']<16){
                    $sub_total+=($value['price']*$value['quantity'])+$toppings_price;
                }else{
                    $sub_total+=($value['price']*$value['quantity']);
                }
            }
        }
        $grand_total = $sub_total;
        ?>
```

When i clicked on the "remove" button it loads to the same page but item row doesn't get removed.

Comment: Where exactly your `remove item` function is ??

Comment: `print_r("<div><a href='".base_url()."index.php/Cart/remove/".$value['item_id']."' class='btn btn-danger'>Remove</a></div>");
` Here is my remove button in the view and remove item function is in the Cart Controller.

Comment: You need to add the `/Cart/remove` function code to your question so we can see what's happening

Comment: @BurhanKashour /Cart/remove code has been added

Comment: @Natasha Bharathi have your problem is solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your userdata is not the values themselves but the array containing them. You need to remove the item from the array and then save the array as the new userdata. Try something like this:

```
public function remove($id){
  $this->load->library('session');
  $list = $this->session->userdata('cart_items');

  if($list){
    foreach ($list as $item=>$value){
      if($id==$value['item_id']){
        unset($list[$item]);
        $list = array_values($list); // optional, reindex the array.
        break;
      }
    }

    $this->session->set_userdata('cart_items', $list);
  }

  redirect('Cart/index');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function remove($id){
        $this->load->library('session');
        $list = $this->session->userdata('cart_items');
        if($list){
            foreach ($list as $item=>$value){
                if($id==$value['item_id']){
                    $this->session->unset_userdata($value['item_id']);
                }
            }
        }
        redirect('Cart/index');

    }
```

**View Code:-**

```
<td>
<a href="<?= base_url().'user/remove/'.$value['item_id']; ?>">
  <button>REMOVE</button>
</a>
</td>
```

**destroy or unset the value of the session?**

```
 $this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

**and for multiple data you can:-**

```
$array_items = array('username' => '', 'email' => '');

$this->session->unset_userdata($array_items);
```

**and to destroy the session:-**

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

**Note:-** For more information about Session Class in Codeigniter,

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I'm not using cart library here and all my items are in a session array as shown above, how can I remove each item from the session?